# Chrome devtools - where did "detached dom tree" go?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the latest version of chrome (mac), I can't find "detached dom tree" anywhere in the memory heap snapshot.  All of the tutorials prior to the last year show it in screenshots.

Was this moved to somewhere else?   Or would it appear if there were any?

Comment: Seems to be working for me https://puu.sh/CvXOh/0b3a021d12.png

Comment: that's a specific element - which I see as well.  Until recently, they had a separate thing that contained all elements (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/imgs/expanded-detached.png)... and I guess they break them out now

Comment: Indeed they've reworked it in https://crrev.com/c/890260

Comment: thanks!  btw, you know how to tell dive into the native memory that chrome task manager reports vs just the javascript VM?

Comment: You'd have to profile it in a specialized tool for native code I guess. Like Visual Studio in Windows.